# FullCalendar.js - How Do You Style the Monthly Forward and Back Buttons?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have an instance of FullCalendar that looks like:

[image]

How do I style the back and forward buttons on the calendar here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key was to change both the background color and the background image of the buttons if you want to change the color of the buttons:

```
.fc-right .fc-prev-button, .fc-right .fc-next-button{
    background-color: #b1d583;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the forward and back buttons FullCalendar gives them classes by default. On mine there is fc-prev-button and fc-next-button respectively. You can just target these with js after the calendar is loaded to style them.